# Как добавить пробелы в нужный момент в словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

У меня такая проблема: есть большой словарь, где последней ключ это описание машины.
Парсер берёт всё это описание get_text() и запихивает в словарь. Но, к сожалению, в начале слова сливаются, так как на сайте они разделены <br>, а парсер не добавляет в словарь \n .

```
'description': item.find('div', class_='other-info').get_text()
```

в итоге мне выводит текст слипшийся.

```
" На учете в Эстонии, техосмотр до 03.2022Купленный в стране: ЭстонияМестонахождение автомобиля: Põltsamaa, ЭстонияVahetuse võimalus F15  "
```

Какие есть методы, чтобы добавить в эти места `\n`, так как текст так же динамический?

Comment: А так `item.find('div', class_='other-info').get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён.

```
   for br in description('br'):
        br.replace_with('\n ')
```

возвёл `description': item.find('div', class_='other-info')` в переменную и проматал все значение с br заменив их на \n